# Merge two tables based on rows combination and not to compare every row in the table with the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables
Table_1

| Product | Parts |
| --- | --- |
| A | Z |
| A | X |
| A | Y |

Table_2

| Produkt | Superset | Parts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Superset (Z,X,Y) | Z |
| A | Superset (Z,X,Y) | X |
| A | Superset (Z,X,Y) | Y |
| A | Superset(Z,X) | Z |
| A | Superset(Z,X) | X |

The second table has two superset: Superset (Z,X,Y) and Superset(Z,X).

What I am trying to do is to generate this table.  The first and the second table must be merged!

| Product | Superset | Parts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Superset(Z,X,Y) | Z |
| A | Superset(Z,X,Y) | X |
| A | Superset(Z,X,Y) | Y |

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? If the former 2008 or 2012? Both are also *completely* unsupported so it's time to upgrade. I'm removed all the conflicting tags for now; you'll need to [edit] the question to (re)tag appropriately.

Comment: What about the version?

Comment: Sorry, i can't get your logic... Why the last item is with Parts='X'?

Comment: You might wanna explain the logic of the merging. I don't see it

Comment: It was a typo! i edited the last table. imagine that we have four tables (products, parts, parts_superset and employee_entries)

I just want to be able to compare what in the employee entries table with the base data stored in Parts Superset. notice one product can use the same parts.